# How to remove duplicates from youtube playlist

Tags: youtube

How to remove duplicates from youtube playlist? is there any tool/ site to scan for duplicates in playlist automatically, then remove them?

Comment: you can enter videos into spreadsheet and remove duplicates. are you interested in this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by opening the playlist in YouTube (**not** YouTube Music). If you then clock the 3-dot-menu and select "Settings" and then "Advanced Settings". After that a "Remove Duplicates" appears on the right which you have to click until it doesn't find any duplicates anymore.

This seems to have worked for me. I still hope there will be a better integration in YouTube Music at some point.

It is described in detail [here](https://www.smartprix.com/bytes/youtube-music-guide-how-to-tips-and-tricks/).

Comment: Two months later: [deprecated](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/09/17/youtube-is-removing-the-button-that-deleted-duplicate-videos-from-playlists/).

Comment: Think of the likely _hundreds_ of engineering hours saved by not having to maintain this complex "remove duplicates" functionality. And the _streamlined_ user experience that we're left with. So what if I have duplicates in my playlists, at least the PMs made their mark. Thanks, Google.